# HTML Form to email issue. What is wrong with the line of code?

Tags: html

```
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Should I change "saveForm" to "Post"? Then where do I insert email address to send to?

Comment: Can you share all of your form code? We need to see more of this to make sense of your logic.

Comment: I cannot add the html form script here as this block does not allow me to. Can you view source at page at link: http://www.sparesite.co.za/index.html

Comment: Right now you have no form 'action.' If you are using just HTML for your form, you could set the form tag like this: <form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">. I am not saying I recommend this at all, but that is a possibility.

Comment: I cannot add the full html form script here as this block does not allow me to. It's asking a lot but can you view source at my page at link: http://www.sparesite.co.za/index.html

Comment: Why do you keep replying with the same statement to every comment or suggestion a user makes?

Answer (score 0):

yes  you can do this with proper form

```
<form action="your page where you send the value"> <label>Name:
</label> <input type="text" name="name"> <label>Email:</label> <input
type="email" name="name"> <input type="submit" name="submit"> </form>
```

Comment: I cannot add the html form script here as this block does not allow me to. Can you look at the script at link:

Comment: I cannot add the full html form script here as this block does not allow me to. It's asking a lot but can you view source at my page at link: sparesite.co.za/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add the html form script here as this block does not allow me to. Can you view source at page at link: http://www.sparesite.co.za/index.html